# How move MySql table to another disk?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, table, alter-table

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tablespace-placing.html) it is impossible to use alter table for moving tables. So if I understand correctlly - to move table it is neccessary to do:

1. Create new table
2. Copy all row from old one
3. drop old table
4. Rename new table created.

First of all - it these steps are correct?
Second - is there more beautiful way to this operation?

Comment: use show create table <table_name>; to copy the structure of the table first and then you can use select * from <table_name> into outfile 'file_name'; to unload all the data from one server/disk and then can use load data local infile 'file_name' into table <table_name> to load the data in table or you can take mysqldump of the table only which include structure and data to do the same..hope it helps

Comment: To move InnoDB tablespace without rebuild the entire table:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-moving-data-files-offline.html

Answer (score 2):

1. `SHOW CREATE TABLE real;`  -- to avoid typos
2. edit it change name to `new` and to add `DATA_DIRECTORY= ...` or whatever
3. perform the `CREATE TABLE new ...`
4. `INSERT INTO new SELECT * FROM real;` -- single, fast, step.  But not instantaneous
5. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;`
6. `DROP TABLE old;`

Step 5 is the main added "elegance".  It is atomic and instantaneous; it won't interrupt the live system.  Also, it give you a chance to test the new `real` before `DROP TABLE old`.

If this is InnoDB, you *must* have `innodb_file_per_table` ON before step 3.  Was it ON when the old `real` was created?  If not, `ibdata1` will not free up any space on the old disk.  Resolving this takes several more steps.

(My steps should work fine for a MyISAM table.)

Comment: for large tables (one of mine has 1bio rows), INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM would take forever.

Comment: @mcmillab - It takes a long time to read 100GB from a disk and to write a similar amount of data to another disk.  The read and write _may_ be done in parallel, but I would need more details to say.  My point is that the I/O is possibly the reason it takes "forever", not the choice of `INSERT..SELECT`.  For further discussion, start a new Question; include `CREATE TABLE` for each.

Comment: you are right, of course, but I think there's significant extra overhead in an INSERT... SELECT statement - eg the db is preparing a Rollback in case of failure, which can be far more intensive than a similar 100gb read/write by mysqldump.

Answer (score 2):

I have dealt with this problem myself, and eventually found a more elegant solution than 'create new - copy - switch': detaching, moving and re-importing the underlying tablespace files. This is much more efficient on large and/or heavily indexed tables as MySQL does not have to redo work it has already done.

---

In short, it comes down to the following steps:

```
FLUSH TABLES `table_name` FOR EXPORT;
```

While keeping the connection open, move the tablespace files in a shell:

```
$ mv /var/lib/mysql/database_name/table_name.{ibd,cfg} ~
```

Now back in MySQL release the lock, drop the table, re-create it with the correct `DATA DIRECTORY` and discard its tablespace:

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name`;
DROP TABLE `table_name`;
CREATE TABLE `table_name` /* ... */ DATA DIRECTORY='/path/to/desired/location';
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

Now copy the moved tablespace files to the desired location:

```
$ cp -a ~/table_name.{ibd,cfg} /path/to/desired/location
```

And import them:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

---

More background and motivation for why 'create new - copy - switch' is inefficient can be found in a blogpost I wrote on this topic: https://www.moxio.com/blog/28/moving-individual-mysql-tables-on-disk.

Comment: I tried that procedure and got "Error Code: 1808. Schema mismatch (Table flags don't match)". I took the ibd and cfg files, put them in the original folder and tried the procedure and it worked (so it is like the table flags contained the original folder and it doesn't let me change it). Any ideas?

Comment: See the update at the top of the blogpost. I originally performed these steps with MariaDB. They should also work with MySQL, but they don't due to an open bug (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76142). That bug report also describes a possible workaround.